# trouble installing Google Cloud SDK in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, sdk, cloud

I'm trying to install Google Cloud SDK in ubuntu, but getting an error:

```
[root@localhost google-cloud-sdk]# ./install.sh

Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!

File "/home/marilu/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 182

with open(rc_path) as rc_file:

          ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax [root@localhost google-cloud-sdk]#
```

I have installed Python; this is how it looks

```
[root@localhost marilu]# ls -l

drwxr-xr-x  5 marilu marilu     4096 Apr  8 11:35 google-cloud-sdk

drwxrwxr-x 19 marilu marilu     4096 Apr 23 09:08 Python-2.7.6

[root@localhost marilu]#
```

Can someone help me? Why this error?

Answer (score 23):

1 Download and install Google Cloud SDK by running the following command in your shell or Terminal:

> curl
>   https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash
>   | bash

2  Restart your shell or Terminal.

3 Authenticate to Google Cloud Platform by running `gcloud auth login`.

Did you try that?

Comment: How di I restart the shell on a server. Is there an alternative.

Comment: use `source ~/.profile && source ~/.bashrc` instead of step 2

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -

sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk

gcloud init
```

Answer (score 1):

As at the time of writing, the install.sh and install.py require Python 2.7, and I have observed a similar error when the default/system Python is version 3+. You can confirm that by running `python --version`.

You have several ways to work around this:

1. Set an environment variable to tell install.sh which python to use, i.e. add the following line to ~/.bashrc:

`export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/path/to/python2.7`

Then `source ~/.bashrc` and rerun install.py

or
 2. Create a python2.7 [Virtual Environment](http://usrnotes.blogspot.com.au/2014/06/python-development-environment-setup-in.html), activate it, and then run install.sh

You can find the location of the installed python2.7 executable by running `which python2.7`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apt-get](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get) to install the Cloud SDK in an Ubuntu/Debían System.

Answer (score 0):

**Install google cloud SDK by running the single command:**

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list && curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add - && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-java && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk-app-engine-python && gcloud init
```

Hope your issue will be resolved.